# If $a,b,c$ are three distinct positive real numbers then the number of real roots of $ax^2+2b|x|-c=0$ are

Tags: quadratics

The equation can have two forms 
$$ax^2+2bx-c+0$$
Or $$ax^2-2bx-c=0$$ both discriminants of the equation are $${4b^2+4ac}$$ which is a positive value so roots are real. Then there should be four roots of the given equation, but answer says there are only two. How is that possible?

Comment: Each form of the equation holds under a condition for the root. The first form under the condition that $x\geq0$, while the second form holds under the condition that $x<0$. The roots found for each equation need to be filtered according to whether they satisfy or not the corresponding condition.

Comment: For example, the first form has the solution $\frac{-2b-\sqrt{4b^2+4ac}}{2a}<0$, which is negative. But the first form is equivalent to the original equation only for $x\geq0$. Therefore, this one is not a solution of the original equation.

Comment: @conditionalMethod how do you know that the first from is $<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^2 = |x|^2$ the given equation is same as:$$a|x|^2+2b|x|-c=0$$

This is a quadratic in $|x|$ and the quadratic formula gives $$|x|=(-b\pm \sqrt{b^2+ac})/a$$
However you must discard the negative root $(-b-\sqrt{b^2+ac})/a$ because $|x|$ is nonnegative.

$$|x| = (-b+\sqrt{b^2+ac})/a\Rightarrow x = \pm(-b+\sqrt{b^2+ac})/a$$

Answer (score 1):

I got
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{b}{a}\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{c}{a}}$$
or
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{b}{a}\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{b}{a}}$$
only $x_1$ (in both cases) are solutions.

Comment: What’s wrong with $x_2$

Comment: $x_2$ is negative.

Comment: But $|x|$ must be positive. $x$ on its own can be positive or negative

Comment: $$x_2=-\frac{b}{a}-\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{c}{a}}<0$$ and $$x_2=\frac{b}{a}-\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{c}{a}}<0$$ since $a,b,c>0$

Comment: Yes, but my question was why can’t $x_2$ be negative, since it’s getting squared or $| |$ anyway